# How to avoid paging in Sitecore Workbox

Tags: workbox

If Sitecore workbox contains more than 10 items, then it start to show paging in the Draft/Awaiting Approval Section in bottom as highlighted with red rectangle in below image

[image]

Do anybody know how to avoid paging and show all items on Draft/Awaiting Approval Section in workbox?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest option would be to set the 'Items per page' to a higher value (you can choose 10, 25, 50, 100 or All)

You could potentially set that as the standard by running something like `Registry.SetInt("Current_User/Workbox/Page Size", 50);` when someone logs in or opens the workbox, as that's the setting Sitecore checks when loading up the panel.

(PS. 999999 seems to be the value for 'All')

**Edit**
Keep in mind this might affect the load time for the workbox if someone has a lot of items in the workbox